# Portuguese language artists similar to Billy Joel or other "classic rock"?

Tags: similar-artists

I'm learning Portuguese (specificially the Brazilian flavor), and was wondering if anyone knows of specific Brazilian/Portuguese language artists that have a similar sound to American/English-language Classic Rock such as Billy Joel or Pink Floyd. Doesn't necessarily need to be similar lyrical sounds/meanings, more just the actual musical style, and with the somewhat slower lyrics, to aid in comprehension.

I tried googling, "Portuguese language artists similar to Billy Joel", but it just comes up with other English-language artists, and all the results say "missing term: portuguese" lol.

Comment: You can try Engenheiros do Hawaii, Os Mutantes, Nenhum de Nós, Barão Vermelho, Titãs/